# Creating an Equation that Represents a Value That Depreciates Per Annum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In my algebra class, we are learning about calculated values that are depreciating over a specific amount of time. We were given an example that I cannot figure out for the life of me. The question states:

"a person buys a car for $25,000 in January 2017. If the car depreciates at a rate of 12.5% per annum, write an equation that represents the value of the car."

I've tried, but everything I come up with ends up giving me a negative value after 3 years. I think I may be using the incorrect form of the equation...

Answer (score 0):

The car depeciates 12.5 % / year. Did your teacher say whether the depreciation is straight-line or cumulative?

If it's straight-line, then it will lose 12.5% of 25,000 = $3,125/year.
After 8 years, it's worthless and goes to the salvage yard.

Can you write a formula for a function that is 25,000 at time 0, and
decreases by 3,125 per unit of time?

If it's cumulative,

At the end of the first year, it will be (100-12.5)% = 87.5% of its starting value.

At the end of the second year, it will be 87.5% of its value at the end of the first year: 87.5% × 87.5% × 25,000.

At the end of the third year, it will be 87.5% of its value at the end of the second year: 87.5% × 87.5% × 87.5% × 25,000.

Can you spot the pattern here? Can you write the formula for what will be after N years (Hint: Use a power.)

Comment: My teacher did not specify whether or not the depreciation is cumulative, but I would assume that it is. would the equation be 25000×0.875^n?

Comment: Right you are.  Now the accountants have a whole bunch of other depreciation formulas that go by names like Accelerated Cost Recovery System, and Sum of Year Digits, but since you're in a precalculus class and not a business class, I'm sure your teacher isn't after those!